# [python][js][eel]Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8000/index.html' caused an error: File does not exist.(the last ask was not answered)

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, eel

I ran into a problem, if you look at the page that runs when you run the python file, then this error pops up. Sorry, the requested URL 'http://localhost:8000/index.html' caused an error:

File does not exist.

ok, if run via cmd, then:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\LP\py\Baym\logic.py", line 10, in 
eel.start("index.html")
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eel_*init*_.py", line 200, in start
run_lambda()
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\eel_*init*_.py", line 191, in run_lambda
btl.run(
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3175, in run
server.run(app)
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bottle_websocket\server.py", line 17, in run
server.serve_forever()
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 398, in serve_forever
self.start()
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\baseserver.py", line 336, in start
self.init_socket()
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\pywsgi.py", line 1545, in init_socket
StreamServer.init_socket(self)
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 180, in init_socket
self.socket = self.get_listener(self.address, self.backlog, self.family)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 192, in get_listener
return _tcp_listener(address, backlog=backlog, reuse_addr=cls.reuse_addr, family=family)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent\server.py", line 288, in _tcp_listener
sock.bind(address)
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gevent_socketcommon.py", line 563, in bind
return self._sock.bind(address)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 10048]

my code:

logic.py:

```
#pip install eel
import eel

eel.init("web") 

@eel.expose 
def ret(x):
    print(x)

eel.start("index.html")

i
```

ndex.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <title>s</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text">
    <button onclick="data"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
function data(){
    var x = document.getElementById("text").value
    eel.ret(x)()
}
```

ok, I searched through the jeepity chat, it didn't help, I searched on the forums, it didn't help. Eventually came here and I found a solution. Which didn't work for me(
(There, it seems, people said to find the name of the file through the OS module, enter it into a variable, and already enter it into eel.start(), as I said, it did not help)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your static files in the web directory

`https://github.com/python-eel/Eel#starting-the-app`

`Suppose you put all the frontend files in a directory called web, including your start page main.html, then the app is started like this;`

eel.init('web')

```
app
├─logic.py
└─web(path name -> eel.init('web'))
    ├─index.html
    ├─main.js
    ├─css
    └─img
```

```
eel.init()

-> def init(path: str, allowed_extensions: List[str] = ['.js', '.html', '.txt', '.htm',
                                    '.xhtml', '.vue'], js_result_timeout: int = 10000) -> None:

path : points to your static file directory name
```

```
import eel

eel.init("web")


@eel.expose
def ret(x):
    print(x)


eel.start("index.html")
```

When you modify the name of the web directory, you need to synchronously fix the path of init to the name you modified